# Find the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{\sin(\sin(\sin x))}$

Tags: calculus, functions, solution-verification, contest-math

> Find the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{\sin(\sin(\sin x))}$

**My Attempt:**

$\sin(\sin(\sin x))\ge0$

$\sin(\sin x)\in[0,1]$

$\sin x\in[0,\arcsin1]$

$x\in[0,\arcsin(\arcsin1)]$

Is this correct?

[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sqrt%5B%5C%2840%29sin%5C%2840%29sin%5C%2840%29sinx%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%5D) doesn't seem to agree.

Comment: Consider the cases $\sin(x) \ge 0$ and $\sin(x) < 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need

- $\sin(\sin(\sin x))\ge0$

which requires

- $2k\pi \le \sin(\sin x)\le \pi+2k\pi \iff 0 \le \sin(\sin x)\le 1$

which requires

- $2k\pi \le\sin x\le \pi+2k\pi \iff 0\le \sin x \le 1$

which requires

- $2k\pi \le x\le \pi+2k\pi$

Answer (score 4):

Case 1:
$$
\begin{align}
 \sin(x) \ge 0 &\implies 0 \le \sin(x) \le 1 \\
&\implies 0 \le \sin(\sin(x)) \le 1\\
&\implies 0 \le \sin(\sin(\sin(x))) \le 1
\end{align}
$$
Case 2:
$$
\begin{align}
 \sin(x) < 0 &\implies -1 \le \sin(x) < 0 \\
&\implies -1 \le \sin(\sin(x)) \le < 0 \\
&\implies -1\le \sin(\sin(\sin(x))) < 0
\end{align}
$$

This shows that $\sin(\sin(\sin(x)))\ge 0$ if and only if $\sin(x) \ge 0$, that is if $2k \pi \le x \le 2(k+1)\pi$ for some integer $k$.